# Cannot get draggable to work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Any ideas on how to get this to work? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mZczk/)

Here's the jQuery:

```
$("#image").draggable({
    stop:function(event,ui) {
        var wrapper = $("#wrapper").offset();
        var borderLeft = parseInt($("#wrapper").css("border-left-width"),10);
        var borderTop = parseInt($("#wrapper").css("border-top-width"),10);
        var pos = ui.helper.offset();
        $("#source_x").val(pos.left - wrapper.left - borderLeft);
        $("#source_y").val(pos.top - wrapper.top - borderTop);
        alert($("#source_x").val() + "," + $("#source_y").val());
    }
});​
```

Comment: do you mean the alert showing undefind, undefined for your x y position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector in your fiddle is missing a #

Comment: Wow.. I can't belive i missed that! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have forked your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4WTZU/

in your fiddle you are miss the `#` in `$("dragmotto")`

it should be `$("#dragmotto").draggable();`

Answer (score 0):

to fix the alert showing `undefind` :

```
$("#dragmotto").draggable({
    stop:function(event,ui) {
        var wrappermotto = $("#wrappermotto").offset();
        var borderLeft = parseInt($("#wrappermotto").css("border-left-width"),10);
        var borderTop = parseInt($("#wrappermotto").css("border-top-width"),10);
        var pos = ui.helper.offset();

        var x = $("#dragmotto").val(pos.left - wrappermotto.left - borderLeft);
        alert(x.val());
    }
});
```